# Python: Update Local Variable in a Parallel Process from Parent Program

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, parent-child

I am relatively new to programming, and what I am asking might be a task that is not possible.  What I want to do is start a parallel process, which will continuously run until requested to stop by the user.  Once the process has started, I would like to update one of the local variables inside the parallel process from the parent program without stopping the process.  For a very simple example, the parallel process I would like to execute would be the following:

```
import time

def loop(i):
    while 1:
        print i
        i+=1
        time.sleep(1)
```

Which continuously iterates and updates `i`.  For clarity the parent program will contain:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from loop import loop

i = 1
p = Process(target = loop, args = (i))
p.start()
```

From the parent program, once "loop" has be initiated, I would like to be able to change the input "i" to another number and have loop continue to iterate given the next starting value.  If anybody has any ideas on how to do this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a queue to pass data between the processes:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from loop import loop

i = 1
q = Queue()
q.put(i)
p = Process(target=loop, args=(q, ))
p.start()
```

Whenever you want to transmit a new value of i to the other process, just put it
in the queue.

Change your loop.py module accordingly:

```
def loop(q):
  while True:
    i = q.get()
    print i
```

In your main code, you can put new values for the process:

```
while True:
  i+=1
  q.put(i)
  time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: If you want your `i` to continue increasing by 1 until a new value is passed, in the consumer you can write `i = (i + 1) if q.empty() else q.get()`. I'd also use a `maxsize=1` on the `Queue` constructor so putting blocks if the queue already has an item in it.

Comment: @kindall: I like this a lot, it was missing in my answer

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong with a queue here, but it's probably more idiomatic to use "shared memory" instead.  Less overhead.  Here's an example self-contained program:

```
import time

def loop(i):
    while 1:
        print i.value
        i.value += 1
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from multiprocessing import Process, Value

    i = Value("i", 1)  # "i" for integer, initial value 1
    p = Process(target=loop, args=(i,))
    p.start()
    for base in range(100, 600, 100):
        time.sleep(2)
        i.value = base
```

That will probably ;-) display:

```
1
2
100
101
200
201
300
301
400
401
500
501
502
503
504
505
506
...
```

But caution:  in return for being speedier, this is also more brittle.  The kinds of data you can share this way are basically inherited from the C language, and aren't generally as rich as Python data types.  In the example above, the type code `"i"` means we're sharing a signed C `int`, which is usually a 32-bit signed integer.  If, for example, `i.value` reaches 2147483647, and we add 1 to it, it will suddenly become -2147483648 (yup, negative!).  Python ints are unbounded, but C ints aren't.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [queue](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/queue.html). (python 2 is `Queue`)

There are a few ways to consume from the queue.  The naive implementation (i.e. the one that has a race condition) is simply to do `if q.empty()`.  This is bad practice but wouldn't hurt you since it's not mission critical if you miss a tick.

The better method is to use exceptions for flow control:

```
q = queue.Queue()
try:
    q.get(False) #non-blocking get()
    #update value of i, etc
except queue.Empty:
    #do stuff here as before
```