# Python: Dynamically Update Array Cells from Parent Program

Tags: python, arrays, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, parent-child

I previously asked a question about updating a single value in a parallel process from a parent program.  Great answers to this can be found at [Python: Update Local Variable in a Parallel Process from Parent Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233246/python-update-local-variable-in-a-parallel-process-from-parent-program/19234437?noredirect=1#19234437).  Now I would like to extend this question to arrays.  Say I have the following simple program that iterates through the first cell of an defined array (similar to the link provided):

```
import time

def loop(i):
    while 1:
        print i[0]
        i[0] += 1
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from multiprocessing import Process, Array

    i = Array("i", [1,2,3,4])
    p = Process(target=loop, args=(i,))
    p.start()
    time.sleep(2)
    # update i in shared memory???
```

From this program, how can I update "i" so the "loop" function continues to run and reads the new array? For example, if I want to set "i" to [50,51,52,53]. Is there an equivalent attribute like "value" that can do this? I did much searching around and could not find any solutions.  Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To update `i` *in-place* use

```
i[:] = [50, 51, 52,53]
```

Note that it is important that you modify `i` in-place because if you were to assign `i` to a new value, such as by using

```
i = [50, 51, 52, 53]
```

Then `i` would simply point to a new list, without modifying the shared array.

The Python idiom `i[:] = [...]` is also used for modifying Python lists in-place, by the way.

---

```
import time

def loop(i):
    while 1:
        print list(i)
        # i[0] += 1
        i[:] = [50,51,52,53]
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from multiprocessing import Process, Array

    i = Array("i", [1,2,3,4])
    p = Process(target=loop, args=(i,))
    p.start()
```

Comment: Thanks you for the response.  Is there a way to adjust the size of the list without resulting in an error? Say I want to change the list to i[:] = [50, 51].

Comment: No, unlike Python lists, the `multiprocessing.Array` allocates a fixed amount of space. You can neither expand nor shrink the Array. You could artificially "shrink" it by using a `multiprocessing.Value` to record the last index in the array, or by placing a bogus or sentinel value after the last valid value.